# ArrayList of abstract and nested classes conflict

Tags: java, list, arraylist, kotlin, casting

I have an adapter:

```
class PhotoAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoAdapter.AbstractViewHolder>() {

    fun addItems(list: ArrayList<AbstractItem>) {
        val position = items.size
        items.addAll(list)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(position, list.size)
    }

    abstract class AbstractItem(
        open val id: Int
    )

    class PhotoItem(
        override val id: Int,
        val url: String?
    ) : AbstractItem(id)

    ...
}
```

and a fragment where it is used:

```
val adapter = PhotoAdapter()
val list: ArrayList<PhotoAdapter.PhotoItem> = ArrayList(emptyList<PhotoAdapter.PhotoItem>())
adapter.addItems(list)
```

But despite of `PhotoItem` is nested from `AbstractItem` I cannot compile:

[image]

If I change `ArrayList` in `addItems()` to simply `List`, it compiles:

```
fun addItems(list: List<AbstractItem>) {
...
```

Probably type cast will also work, but I didn't check.

[image]

The question is why realization (`ArrayList`) and interface (`List`) have different points of view on nested classes?

UPDATE

I rewrote to Java, it will be more clear.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.AbstractViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<AbstractItem> items;

    public void addItems(ArrayList<AbstractItem> list) {
        int position = items.size();
        items.addAll(list);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(position, list.size());
    }

    abstract class AbstractViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public AbstractViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractItem {
        int id;
    }

    public class PhotoItem extends AbstractItem {
        int id;
        String url;
    }
}

public class Example {

    void init() {
        ArrayList<Adapter.PhotoItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
        adapter.addItems(list);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you look closely at the "type mismatch" error message in your first screenshot, you can see that the type of ArrayList you used is the problem, not your own class. You probably imported different ArrayList classes in the different code files. Check your imports.

Comment: @TheBlackIPs, I also thought so, but for Kotlin `ArrayList`s from Kotlin and Java are equal. I llked at `TypeAliases.kt`: `@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias ArrayList<E> = java.util.ArrayList<E>`.

Comment: Okay, I just noticed the comment in your screenshot indicating that the two ArrayList classes are equivalent. My bad. Can you try using the java ArrayList in your code fragment anyway?

Comment: @TheBlackIPs, thanks, I rewrote classes to Java, please, see, if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Because `List` is covariant (it's defined as `List<out T>`), so `List<PhotoAdapter.PhotoItem>` is a subtype of `List<AbstractItem>`. But `MutableList` and `ArrayList` are invariant, which means `ArrayList<PhotoAdapter.PhotoItem>` is not a subtype (or a supertype) of `ArrayList<AbstractItem>`.

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance for a detailed explanation why (I don't think there is much point to duplicating it here).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it.

Answer (score 1):

In java it can be solved by declaring

```
void addItems(ArrayList<? extends AbstractItem> list)
```

I don't know what is kotlin syntax for that.

Comment: It's `fun addItems(list: ArrayList<out AbstractItem>)`.